# Wrapper Boolean VS Primitive boolean

Tags: java, boolean, wrapper

I am using Lombok.

This is how my Metadata file looks like.

```
package com.some.test.check.meta;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
public class CSVSourceProbeMetaData {
    private boolean backupEnabled;
    private String streamingDir;
    private String filePattern;
}
```

But when I try to access `backupEnabled` from here in the class file, it doesn't give me suggestions and it is red.

```
public Object execute() {
        boolean backupEnabled = csvSourceProbeMetaData.get_______();
        String streamingDir = csvSourceProbeMetaData.getStreamingDir();
```

But when I use Wrapper class it works fine. Is this because I cannot use primitive boolean here or any other reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The getter method name for boolean will start with is not get so try isBackupEnabled this will work with you

Check this for more details 
https://www.baeldung.com/lombok-getter-boolean

Comment: Thank you so much. 
Sorry, Cannot upvote you since I don't have 15+ reputations. Really appreciate the comment though!

Comment: It's okay I just wanna help ;)